# ImportError: No module named zmq

Tags: zeromq

I have installed zeroMQ, but when I run the example of gr-ofdm, there is still "ImportError: No module named zmq" errors.

```
./run_benchmark_gui.sh 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zhenyu/gr-ofdm/gr-ofdm/apps/gui/ofdm_tx_gui.py", line 28, in <module>
    from gnuradio import zeromq
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/zeromq/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from probe_manager import probe_manager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/zeromq/probe_manager.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zmq
ImportError: No module named zmq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zhenyu/gr-ofdm/gr-ofdm/apps/gui/ofdm_rx_gui.py", line 28, in <module>
    from gnuradio import zeromq
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/zeromq/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from probe_manager import probe_manager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/zeromq/probe_manager.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zmq
ImportError: No module named zmq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zhenyu/gr-ofdm/gr-ofdm/apps/../python/ofdm/benchmark_ofdm.py", line 23, in <module>
    from gnuradio import gr, blocks, analog, zeromq
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/zeromq/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from probe_manager import probe_manager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/zeromq/probe_manager.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zmq
ImportError: No module named zmq
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You may have installed `ØMQ` but you haven't installed `pyzmq` module in your Python interpreter. Try: `python -m pip install pyzmq`

Comment: Solved! thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this commands:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py

/usr/local/bin/python2.7 ez_setup.py

/usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7 zmq
```